# Get all combination with n -length from a list

Tags: python

I was wondering how to get all the possible combinations from a list with n-length from python. But there is one catch. It's hard for me to explain as English is not my native language. So I give an example:

If I have a list:

```
my_List = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want it to get an output of with length 3 to be

```
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 1, 3)
(1, 1, 4)
etc etc
```

But I do NOT want to have repeated lists. By that I mean, if I already have

```
(1, 1, 2)
```

I do not have any need for

```
(1, 2, 1) and
(2, 1, 1)
```

Does that make any sence? Any help woudl be much apreciated

Comment: [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/python-code-to-pick-out-all-possible-combinations-from-a-list

Comment: I deleted my answer. falsetru is correct, you want `combinations_with_replacement`, not `combinations`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> my_List = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> for xs in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(my_List, 3):
...     print(xs)
...
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 1, 3)
(1, 1, 4)
(1, 2, 2)
(1, 2, 3)
...
```

Comment: Yes thank you. I figured it out yesterday. I just checked stackoverflow now. :) Have a nice day