# Get all combinations of a list in Python

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I would like to get all combinations of a list:

```
L = ["a","b","c"]
combinations(L,length=2)
# [("a","a"),("a","b"),("a","c"),("b","a"),("b","b"),("b","c"),("c","a"),("c","b"),("c","c")]
```

I've tried

`itertools.combinations()`

but this returned

`[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c')]`

When I use `itertools.permutations()`, it just returns the combinations with the length of the iteration, which is also not what I want.

Any librarys / function that I can use, without writing my own?

Comment: You mean `permutations` not `combinations`. Try that function instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all combination with n -length from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536725/get-all-combination-with-n-length-from-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the second parameter of [`itertools.permutations()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
from itertools import permutations

L = ["a","b","c"]

print([n for n in permutations(L,2)]+[(i,i) for i in L])
```

Output:

```
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b'), ('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('c', 'c')]
```

From the documentation:

```
itertools.permutations(iterable, r=None)
```

*Return successive r length permutations of elements in the iterable.
If r is not specified or is None, then r defaults to the length of the iterable and all possible full-length permutations are generated.*

Answer (score 4):

You can use `itertools.product` with `repeat=2` like so:

```
from itertools import product

L = ["a","b","c"]
print(list(product(L, repeat=2)))
#[('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b'), ('c', 'c')]
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, using permutations to generate a product is a misuse of the itertools module.

Answer (score 3):

A simple list comprehesion can do the job too.

```
L = ["a","b","c"]
print([(a,b) for a in L for b in L])
#[('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b'), ('c', 'c')]
```

Comment: Is there a way to put it in a function, so I can do `combinations(["a","b","c"], length=xyz)`?

Comment: As other answers suggest, I guess for variable length using `itertools.product` might be easier.

Answer (score 2):

`itertools` module has a function called `product` which is what you are looking for.

```
>>> L = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> list(itertools.product(L, repeat=2))
[('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b'), ('c', 'c')]
```

Answer (score 2):

The product function from itertools offers a solution.

```
In [17]: from itertools import product

In [18]: L = ["a","b","c"]

In [19]: list(product(L, L))
Out[19]:
[('a', 'a'),
 ('a', 'b'),
 ('a', 'c'),
 ('b', 'a'),
 ('b', 'b'),
 ('b', 'c'),
 ('c', 'a'),
 ('c', 'b'),
 ('c', 'c')]
```